# PHP regular expression for user_code where letters must follow numners

Tags: php, regex

I want to have PHP regular expression for the following condition:

- 2254e → applicable
- 2254aaa → applicable
- 22e54 → No applicable data
- a2254 → No applicable data
- 22540 → No applicable data

The letters must come after the digits.

Comment: I don't understand what the above sequence is supposed to mean.  What are your requirements?

Comment: user code consists of digits and letters. I need a regex where I can check that all letters are at the end following the letters.

for example:
user_code => 1234abc is right
user_code => 12abc34 is wrong

Comment: `/^\d+[A-z]+$/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regular expression for having the first digits will be denoted by `\d` with `+` for one or many and then combine with `[a-zA-Z]` for having a letter with lowercase as well as uppercase followed by `+`. So the overall regex will be `/^\d+[a-zA-Z]+$/`

Comment: I think there is a typo in your overall regex. The last `z` should be uppercase `^\d+[a-zA-Z]+$`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks for pointing out. I have updated the answer.